# GWT-Ext migration to native gwt. Is JavaScriptObjectHelper analog in native gwt v2.4?

Tags: gwt, gwt-ext

I am working on migrating a large GWT application from gwt-ext to native GWT v2.4. In gwt-ext there is a class called JavaScriptObjectHelper. Is there a corresponding class in the native gwt libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some methods from `JavaScriptObjectHelper` are available elsewhere: `JavaScriptObject.createObject()` and `createArray()`, `JsArray`and friends, `Element`'s methods (`getProperty`, `getAttribute`, etc.), and of course `Boolean.valueOf()` and similar methods on `Integer`, `Float`, `Date`, etc.

A few other methods have no equivalent though: `apply`, `arrayConvert`, `convertMapToJavaScriptArray`, etc.